# delayed_job: how to check for presence of a particular job based on a triggered method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a method like this that goes through an array to find different APIs and launch a `delayed_job` instance for every API found like this.

```
def refresh_users_list
  apis_array.each do |api| 
    api.myclass.new.delay.get_and_create_or_update_users
  end
end
```

I have an `after_filter` on `users#index` controller to trigger this method. This is creating many jobs to be triggered that will eventually cause `too many connections` problems on Heroku.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can check for the presence of a Job in the database by each of the API that the array iterates. This would be very helpful so I can only trigger a particular refresh if that api wasn't updated on a given time.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `config/application.rb`, add the following

   ```
   config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/jobs/**/"]
   ```
2. Create a new directory at `app/jobs/`.
3. Create a file at `app/jobs/api_job.rb` that looks like

   ```
   class ApiJob < Struct.new(:attr1, :attr2, :attr3)

     attr_accessor :token

     def initialize(*attrs)

       self.token = self.class.token(attr1, attr2, attr3)
     end

     def display_name
       self.class.token(attr1, attr2, attr3)
     end

     #
     # Class methods
     #
     def self.token(attr1, attr2, attr3)
       [name.parameterize, attr1.id, attr2.id, attr3.id].join("/")
     end

     def self.find_by_token(token)
       Delayed::Job.where("handler like ?", "%token: #{token}%")
     end
   end
   ```

   ***Note:** You will replace `attr1`, `attr2`, and `attr3` with whatever number of attributes you need (if any) to pass to the `ApiJob` to perform the queued task. More on how to call this in a moment*
4. For each of your API's that you queue some `get_and_create_or_update_users` method for you'll create another `Job`. For example, if I have some `Facebook` api model, I might have a class at `app/jobs/facebook_api_job.rb` that looks like

   ```
   class FacebookApiJob < ApiJob
     def perform
       FacebookApi.new.get_and_create_or_update_users(attr1, attr2, attr3)
     end
   end
   ```

   ***Note:** In your Question you did not pass any attributes to `get_and_create_or_update_users`. I am just showing you where you would do this if you need the job to have attributes passed to it.*

**Finally**, wherever your `refresh_users_list` is defined, define something like this `job_exists?` method

```
def job_exists?(tokens)
  tokens = [tokens] if !tokens.is_a?(Array) # allows a String or Array of tokens to be passed

  tokens.each do |token|
    return true unless ApiJob.find_by_token(token).empty?
  end

  false
end
```

Now, within your `refresh_users_list` and loop, you can build new tokens and call `job_exists?` to check if you have queued jobs for the API. For example

```
# Build a token

def refresh_users_list
  apis_array.each do |api| 
    token = ApiJob.token(attr1, attr2, attr3)
    next if job_exists?(token)

    api.myclass.new.delay.get_and_create_or_update_users
  end
end
```

***Note:** Again I want to point out, you won't be able to just drop in the code above and have it work. You **must** tailor it to your application and the job's you're running.*

---

**Why is this so complicated?**

From my research, there's no way to "tag" or uniquely identify a queued job through what `delayed_job` provides. Sure, each job has a unique `:id` attribute. You *could* store the ID values for each created job in some hash somewhere

```
{
  "FacebookApi": [1, 4, 12],
  "TwitterApi": [3, 193, 44],
  # ...
}
```

and then check corresponding hash key for an ID, but I find this limiting, and not always sufficient for the problem When you need to identify a specific job by multiple attributes like above, we must create a way to find these jobs *(**without** loading every job into memory and looping over them to see if one matches our criteria)*.

**How is this working?**

The `Struct` that the `ApiJob` extends has a `:token` attribute. This token is based on the attributes passed *(`attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3`)* and is built when a new class extending `ApiJob` is instantiated.

The `find_by_token` class method simply searches the string representation of the job in the `delayed_job` queue for a match based on a token built using the same `token` class method.

Comment: +1 for complete answer. Have you checked https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#named-queues ?

Comment: Yes, though for my needs I'd have hundreds of queues which seems impractical.